# How to convert date format into something like September 13, 2018 using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to convert this existing html and get the month and date. This single code below

```
<div class="aa">2016-05-31 08:00:00</div>
```

Want to convert the code above into something like this, will just remove the time:

```
<div class="aa">May 31, 2016</div>
```

And then prepend or append 2 divs of Month and the date that have the output of similar to these codes below

```
<div class="bb">May</div>
<div class="cc">31</div>
```

So the final output would look like this:

```
<div class="aa">May 31, 2016</div>
<div class="bb">May</div>
<div class="cc">31</div>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Please update your question with the code that demonstrates your best attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/r370e2x6/5/

```
var input = $.trim($('.aa').text());
$('.aa').text(moment(input).format("MMM DD, YYYY"));
$('.bb').text(moment(input).format("MMM"));
$('.cc').text(moment(input).format("DD"));
```

Here is the moment library required:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js

Comment: hi @kots thanks for the time. But when I tried it on webtool it said "ReferenceError: moment is not defined" ... Any idea?

Comment: do you know where to get this library? prefer a cdn link but if it is a file thats fine. Thank you

Comment: Added cdn link to moment library.

Comment: Hi @kots thanks

The output is "Invalid Date"

This is the message:

Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info. Arguments: [0] _isAMomentObject:

Comment: Ohh works now @kots.. 
    var input = $.trim($('.aa').text());
    $('.aa').text(moment(input, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a').format("MMM DD, YYYY"));

Thanks